# How can the admin-on-rest project will have user registration page?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, loopback, admin-on-rest, react-admin

There is any sample project to have user registration page with working REST API?
For example, loopback backend API will offer registering new user, verifying email, retrieve forgotten password, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pages themselves should be added with [custom routes](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customroutes).

Regarding the REST API, you'll have to refer to your backend API documentation and use whatever is recommended to communicate with it (fetch, axios, etc.).

However, from this point, there will be nothing specific to `react-admin`.